# how can I log out of the jda-discord voice channel

Tags: java, discord-jda

I need the bot itself to exit the discord voice channel, I do not know how to do this, please help.

I tried to kick the bot using the ID, but I couldn't do it.

```
event.getChannel().asVoiceChannel().getGuild().kick(UserSnowflake.fromId(id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you connected to the channel using `guild.getAudioManager().openAudioConnection(channel)`, the logical opposite is how you leave it with `guild.getAudioManager().closeAudioConnection()`.